# Changing web environment URLs automatic

Tags: javascript, php, html, amazon-web-services

I'm currently working on a web project(js, html, php with no frameworks) using AWS technology, including AWS version control. I work locally with Xampp and when I push my code to the master branch there is a trigger that deploys the code to the Production environment.

My main problem now is that I need to manually change the development-production urls or use a html tag and relative URLs, and it's a mess.. When working on development my url is something like: "192.168.64.2/web" and when production it's "myweburl.com". So I need something that checks out my actual URL and change all those over the project. Something like a global variable with the URL to use.

I've read about using "dotenv" and "dotenv-webpack" for environment manage, but I do need to install it on the server, as well as nodejs, and configure .gitignore, and I expect an easier solution. I would like to avoid nodejs. I've searched about my question all around internet but I just find ways that do not convince me, but if this question is repeated just redirect me there.

Is there any secure approach just using javascript, php or a config file?

The objective is having something that depending on my URL (DEV, TEST, PROD) changes all the URLs of my project, and protect the other environment URLs from being seen.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just omit the hostname altogether and use links like: `/foo`? The initial slash will make the link relative from the document root. And as a side note, you don't need to use nodejs to use dotenv. There are PHP implementations for it as well.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm actually doing, but i was looking for a better approach to use it as well for my API dev URL

Comment: Is your API returning links? If not, then I'm not sure what a "better approach" would be. If the API returns links/endpoints to itself, then just add the hostname in some config file, which you override in the different environments. Or use dotenv (the PHP version).

Comment: Also, since you say _"but I just find ways that do not convince me"_, it would be helpful to know what you've found and why they didn't convince you. It helps us from spending time recommending solutions you've already discarded for, to us, unknown reasons.

Comment: dotenv php version is something I could like to use. And well you gave me and idea about using a config file just for each environment with the urls inside and .gitignore it. The ways that do not convince me are just things I found about reverse proxy or installing nodejs on the server. I think I'm gonna try those solutions, thank you Magnus.

Comment: Ah, yes, using nodejs or reverse proxy for this would be overkill. I'm always creating one config that's "global" that contains default values (or dummy values for credentials etc since you don't want those in your git repo) that I keep in the git repo. Then I always create another config containing all environment specific values, and any credentials. That one is git ignored. Then I just read both and override the values in the global config with the env. specific config.

Comment: I'll try it, thank you again! 
Have a nice day Magnus